XMLSerializer binaries need to load from other folder apart from AppBase
The application I am using is Application.exe which will run from C:\App\Bin folder.
This application internally will load C# COM object binaries from the location C:\App\COMDLL.
The COM object is internally using XML Serializers. So we generated those binaries as well for our COM binary using sgen.exe tool.
Since these XML Serializer dlls generated by sgen.exe is related to COM object, we kept in
C:\App\COMDLL folder. But FusionLoader is searching in the AppBase folder which is C:\App\Bin folder. I cannot move the XML Serializer dlls to AppBase.
Is there any way that I can tell to FusionLoader to load the binaries from C:\App\COMDLL folder instead of C:\App\Bin?
I tried using the "AssemblyResolve" event handler. But this didn't help me much.
Solution #1
The code I have written for AssemblyResolve is like this and it didn't work:
public static void RedirectDependency()
{
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ResolveHandler;
  LibLoaded = true;
}
private static bool LibLoaded = false;
public static bool ResolveHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{

  var libName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
  if(libName.Name.EndsWith("XmlSerializers"))
  {
    var libPath = @"C:\App\COMDLL\COMDLL.XmlSerializers.dll";
    return Assembly.Load(libPath);
  }
  return null;
}

Solution #2
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
</configuration>

Here as per the documentation PrivatePath should be subdirectories of AppBase. So in our scenario it is outside, so it didn't work.
I don't have any control on APP code. I only have control on COMDLL project. So please suggest accordingly.

Your relation to COM is obscure here. Unless you use reg-free techniques (do you?) a COM dll is loaded from where it was registered (for example with regasm with .NET), which can be anywhere on the disk (and also in the GAC with .NET, depends on regasm params) so the client cannot choose the location of that dll.

we are using regasm to register the COM dll. So the dll is loaded based on the registry.
but what about XMLSerializer binaries. Those are not loading from that location. it is trying to search on AppBase.

You can use fuslogvw (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) and procmon(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to check what files are loaded from where (filter by your .exe )
